# How to access asynchronous angularjs service data out of the call back function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have a form submission where I need to validate my email id separately. Based on email Id validation (Using `validationService`) I will be submitting the form and will call `formSubmissionService` from my controller.

I want to code the logic like this in my `formController`

```
validationService.getEmailValidationResult.then(function(data){
    $scope.validEmailId = data.exists;
});

if($scope.validEmailId == true){
   formSubmissionService.submitForm().then(function(data){
      $scope.form.submitted = data;
   });
}

if($scope.form.submitted){
    $location.path('formSubmissionResponse');
}
```

After getting some updates from my previous posts I came to know that the 
$scopevalidEmailId Can not be accessed outside of the callback function.

So my code will be rewritten like this

```
validationService.getEmailValidationResult.then(function(data){
    $scope.validEmailId = data.exists;
    if($scope.validEmailId){
        formSubmissionService.submitForm.then(function(data){
            $scope.form.submitted = data;
            if($scope.form.submitted){
               $location.path('formSubmissionResponse');
            }
        )}; 
    }
});
```

Is there any way to achieve the above logic or the code which is rewritten can be improved further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're redirecting, you probably don't need/want to assign to `$scope`.

```
validationService.getEmailValidationResult().then(function(data){
    if (!data.exists) {
        return $q.reject(new Error('bad email!'));
    }

    return formSubmissionService.submitForm();
})
.then(function(submit) {
    if (!submit) {
        return $q.reject(new Error('error submitting'));
    }

    $location.path('formSubmissionResponse');
})
.catch(function(e) {
    // error
});
```

Comment: I have a requirement like, If I am getting the validation result as false then I do not want to propagate to the next then function. Instead I want to return the page itself.

Comment: If `data.exists` is false the next then function will not be called. It will skip to the catch block

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten it a bit more:

```
validationService.getEmailValidationResult.then(function(data){
    $scope.validEmailId = data.exists;
    if($scope.validEmailId){
       return formSubmissionService.submitForm();
    } else return $q.reject();
}).then(function(data){
     $scope.form.submitted = data;
     if($scope.form.submitted){
        $location.path('formSubmissionResponse');
     }
});
```

for more info: http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/